# Save token to localstorage

Tags: token, jwt

```
app.post('/auth', function(req,res){
  console.log("post got", req.body)
  if (req.body.username && req.body.password) {
    db.get("select * from user where username='"+req.body.username+"' and password='"+req.body.password+"';", function(err, row){
        console.log(row)
          if (row && row.username == req.body.username && row.password == req.body.password) {
            var data = req.body;
                  var token = jwt.sign(data, 'shhhhh11');
                  res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    token: token
                  }));
        } else {
            res.end('authentication unsuccsessful');
        }
    });
  }
});
```

So this posts token to auth how can I get the token from auth to post it in localstorage client side?
How can I define the token for it cus just setting it gets me

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: token is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the token to localStorage with:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

You can get the token from localStorage with:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('token');
```

Comment: It doesn't help, I need help with getting posted data and then setting it to localstorage. Uncaught ReferenceError: token is not defined